# MySQL composite index for OR condition

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

I have a huge table on which I want to run a query with an or condition

```
SELECT id, upload_key 
FROM product_data 
WHERE (status = 0 or updated = 0) and uploaded_on is NULL;
```

The table is more than 50 million records now and takes minutes to execute. I tried creating a composite index on keys **status, updated and uploaded_on** (in the same order as query) but it as turns out, the query doesn't use composite indexes with an OR on two different columns.

Is there a way to create indexes to optimize the query, or should I just move uploaded_on as the first where clause and create an single column index on the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the query using `union all`:

```
SELECT id, upload_key 
FROM product_data 
WHERE status = 0 and uploaded_on is NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id, upload_key 
FROM product_data 
WHERE status <> 0 and updated = 0 and uploaded_on is NULL;
```

You want two indexes:  `(status, uploaded_on)` and `(updated, uploaded_on, status)`.

Comment: How will the second query use the index (updated, uploaded_on, status) when they are in different order?

Comment: @sagarkalra . . . I'm not sure I understand your question.  The initial keys in the index need to match the equality conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: In general, the order of things in `WHERE` does not matter; the order in `INDEX` does.  (Though, the order in _these_ indexes probably does not matter.)

Comment: Would there be a problem in keeping the second index smaller (no updated) and using UNION instead of UNION ALL ?

Comment: @John . . . `UNION` incurs overhead for removing duplicates, so it is much less performant.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I guessed that was the reason. As I understand it, the overhead is entirely CPU based as it should have those duplicates already cached in memory and mysql isn't able to multi-thread on a single query. So when working with large tables it might be better to UNION ALL using a small index to trade memory and sdd usage (index storage) for cpu usage ?

Do you know by any chance if the mysql 8+ internal index merging is as efficient as a manual uninon ?